# Как разрешается конфликт имён в Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Ruby - удобный язык, но есть и косяки.

Меня беспокоит, что модули подключаются подобно сишным `#include`. Не до конца ясно, как разрешать конфликты имён.

Если подключать два файла с одинаковыми именами методов/классов, то они просто перетираются последним. Хотя это бывает удобно, но с подключаемыми файлами лучше вести иначе.

Есть ключевое слово `module`, похоже на пространство имён. И с помощью него можно спастись от затирания. Но я провёл эксперимент: если объявить модули, то при подключении модулей с одинаковыми именами происходит молчаливое перетирание функций и классов с одинаковыми именами.

Конечно есть такой вариант: весь распространяемый код должен содержаться в модуле с уникальным названием.

Собственно вопрос. Как в Ruby принято решать такие проблемы? Что ещё мне нужно знать о модульной системе Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature. Цимес Рубина в подобной открытости помимо прочего. Если вас сильно беспокоит (вообще говоря, это не является проблемой до, скажем, определенного уровня использования языка), и хочется пошурудить руками, посмотрите на https://github.com/banister/remix и https://github.com/banister/prepend

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ очень поздний, да, но ответа о том, почему это не проблема, всё ещё нет!*

---

В экосистеме Ruby особенно сильны **конвенции**. Когда язык навязывает так мало, правила вырабатывает само сообщество пользователей. А кто их не соблюдает, тех сообщество может сильно не любить :)

На RubyGems (в основном источнике библиотек) есть [рекомендации по именованию](http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/), соблюдая которые, подобный конфликт получить можно разве что специально. Как? Очень просто: есть конвенции о том, как **на основе названия гема** выяснить, **как должен называться главный модуль** гема и **в каком файле**/**по какому пути** он должен быть размещён.

Ruby не навязывает соблюдение этих правил (в отличие от Java, например). Но соблюдая их, жить в экосистеме языка проще.

#### Исчерпывающий пример:

- Если назвали гем `net-http-digest_auth`
- ...то его главный модуль `Net::Http::DigestAuth` (в котором должна находиться большая часть гема)
- ...а загружается он через `require 'net/http/digest_auth'`

  - Скорее всего, в геме он при этом будет лежать в `lib/net/http/digest_auth.rb`

Т. е. расчёт на то, что RubyGems будет использоваться в качестве основного источника библиотек, и конфликты между библиотеками можно свести к минимуму, просто посмотрев на список гемов оттуда.

И знаете? Практика показывает, что **люди туда смотрят**. То есть, это работает.

---

Это всё, правда, немножко ломается, когда речь заходит о **плагинах**. Т. е. гемах, которые расширяют функциональность других гемов. Иногда случаются конфликты, когда загружаются несколько плагинов к одному гему, т. к. они все как-то влияют на него.

Риск конфликта особенно велик, если расширяемый гем не имеет никакого API для расширений. В этом случае в ход идут грязные приёмы вроде monkeypatch'ей, которые могут закончиться чем угодно.